# Migrate Mdaemon mail server to Google Apps Business

Tags: migration, g-suite, imap, outlook-2007, mdaemon

We are planning to migrate our current **Mdaemon** mail server (50 accounts) with **Imap** to **Google Apps Business**.

Each client have **Outlook 2007** with the **Mdaemon connector 2.2**

There are a lot of informations available on Google site and i read most of all but actually i have some doubts about how to upload/migrate the users emails into Google server.

There are 2 ways to migrate: By Server or By Client

**By Server**

Google offer a nice tool for the [migration by the Imap server but Mdaemon isnt supported](http://services.google.com/apps/resources/admin_breeze/MigratingEmail/).

**By Client**

My choice is try to use the [Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Outlook](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration) but seem support only .PST file and Outlook profiles (Exchange server)

In my mind i thought was something like this below to migrate the users emails:

`Mdaemon server` <- imap connector -> `outlook 2007` -> App Migration -> `Google server`

I am wrong about this scenario above ? or i miss something ?

So are there someone that tried already this kind of migration?
Or someone can give me an idea, a tip, or a guide to complete this step ?

thanks in advance for the suggestions.

p.s. please let me know if i need provide more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs please. Google provides complete documentation for these steps if your mail server supports IMAP. And MDaemon supports IMAP. https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=172212

Comment: thank for your answer, i read it already but wasnt sure 100% about IMAP compatibility RFC3501 by Mdaemon so i'd ask for check if someone did already. Btw now thanks to your answer i feel better and i can use the Google Apps Migration for Microsoft® Exchange for migrate the users email

Comment: @LukaMilani did you have success in this migration?